# How to open a file locally using nodejs express in adobe reader

Tags: node.js, express, fs, acrobat, pdfkit

Hi I want to open a pdf file generated by pdfkit to get stored in local system as well a open it automatically on click of button.
I was able to save the file locally but I am not able to open the pdf file using acrobat automatically.
Please help me on how to achieve this.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Express is a tool to create a web server. Are you trying to use server-side code to run Adobe Reader **on the server** or are you trying to trigger a download to the computer the **browser** is running on which then gets automatically opened in Adobe Reader?

Comment: I am trying to trigger a download to the server , where after download it should open using the adobe reader automatically located in the server.